# How to return to the previous statement after catching an error instead of restarting the whole program in Java?

Tags: java

I recently started learning Java as I have a keen interest in programming. I am currently creating an application that calculates a person's BMI.

Question: Is there a way to return to the previous statement when the user has made a mistake on instead of restarting the whole program (EG: when the line `Please enter your weight in pounds` executed, the user input a non-integer value and an error prompts out saying `Invalid Input`, it will then return to the previous line that the user made an error -> `Please enter your weight in pounds executed`).
If yes, how so?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Body_Mass_Calculation {
    private static int gender, inputAnswer;
    private static boolean wenttocatch;
    private static double myBMI, heightInch, weightPound, weightKilo, heightMeter;
    private static Scanner input_1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    //Questions + Calculation
    static void myMethod() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter gender. 1-- Male  2--Female");

            gender = input_1.nextInt();

            while (gender > 2 || gender < 1) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input!");
                System.out.println("Please enter gender. 1-- Male  2--Female");

                gender = input_1.nextInt();
            }

            if (gender == 1 || gender == 2) {
                System.out.println("Please enter your height in inches. ");
                heightInch = input_1.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Please enter your weight in pounds. ");
                weightPound = input_1.nextInt();

                heightMeter = heightInch * 0.0254;
                weightKilo = weightPound * 0.45359237;
                myBMI = weightKilo / (heightMeter * heightMeter);
            }
            if (gender == 1) {
                if (myBMI >= 27.8)
                    System.out.println("Your body-mass-index is " + df2.format(myBMI) + " this is considered high ! \n \n");
                else
                    System.out.println("Your body-mass-index is " + df2.format(myBMI) + " this is not considered high ! \n \n");
            }

            if (gender == 2) {
                if (myBMI >= 27.3)
                    System.out.println("Your body-mass-index is " + df2.format(myBMI) + " this is considered high ! \n \n");
                else
                    System.out.println("Your body-mass-index is " + df2.format(myBMI) + " this is not considered high! \n \n");
            }

            System.out.println("Do you wish to continue? Enter: 1 -> Yes,  2 -> No.");
            inputAnswer = input_1.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Invalid Input !");

            if (inputAnswer == 2) {           //If input = 2, Program executes line below
                System.out.println("Thank You for using this shitty app !");
                System.exit(2);
            } else if (inputAnswer == 1) {
                myMethod();

            }

        } catch
        (Exception e) {
            input_1.next();
            wenttocatch = true;
            System.out.println("Invalid input !");
            input_1.nextLine();
            myMethod();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Executes Function/Method
        System.out.println("Welcome   ! \n ");
        myMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you need a while loop (possibly a do-while loop). With that, you could check each time if the input is invalid, and if it is, ask the user to reenter it.

Comment: Please remove the white space from your code and follow java code style. It matters. It makes your code easy or hard to read.

Comment: @user Hi thank you for the advice, is it possible for you to show me an example ? I want to learn/know how Do-While loop can be implemented in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. The solution is to write a method that takes care of it. Instead of writing a ton of code and repeating yourself, you use a method to encapsulate some functionality, so that you can invoke it a lot without copying code. For example, instead of:

```
System.out.println("Please enter gender. 1-- Male  2--Female");
gender = input_1.nextInt();
while (gender > 2 || gender < 1) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input!");
    gender = input_1.nextInt();
}
```

you really just want to write something like:

```
gender = askInt("Please enter gender. 1-- Male  2-- Female", 1, 2);
```

where the `askInt` is a method you write which takes the text you want to show as prompt, along with the smallest and largest valid value.

Now that you have this function, you can expand its functionalities and all the code that uses this function gets the functionality automatically. So, if you add 'catch invalid input exceptions and re-ask' functionality to this one method, *ALL* the questions get it.

```
int askInt(String prompt, int min, int max) {
    int result;
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(prompt);
        result = input.nextInt();
        if (result >= min && result <= max) return result;
        System.out.println("Invalid input!");
    }
}
```

This basic loop will keep looping until the `if` clause is triggered, causing the method to return, which is the only way out. You can now add handling for `NumberFormatException` within this one method, within the while loop. You can't go back to the line that caused the problem, but you can go forward, and in a while loop, going forward automatically jumps back to the start (i.e., that's how to go 'backwards'). So, we mix a while loop (which can go backwards) and a catch block, and that's how to solve the problem. And then we put all this in a method, so that we can write this code only once, instead of having to repeat it every time.

Comment: Hi there, for the 

int askInt(String prompt, int min, int max) {
    int result;
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(prompt);
        result = input.nextInt();
        if (result >= min && result <= max) return result;
        System.out.println("Invalid input!");
    }
}


Im not entirely sure where to  put this block of code as I kept getting syntax error...

Comment: same place you put your main method. inside a class (not inside another method).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using a `do { _code1 } while (_condition)` which execute the `_code` until `_condition` is false.

And `_code1` is a `try {}catch` which will catch any exception (error) thrown from inside the `try {}` block.
Here the exception (error) is thrown if the user enters a character instead of a digit.

```
System.out.println("Please enter gender. 1-- Male  2--Female");

int gender = 0 ;
do {
    try {
        if (gender == -1) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input!");
            System.out.println("Please enter gender. 1-- Male  2--Female");
        }

        gender = input_1.nextInt () ;

    }catch (Exception e){
        gender = -1 ;
    }
    
}while (gender > 2 || gender < 1);
```

Comment: Hi I tried to implement this and run and it won't stop looping after I entered an invalid input

Comment: @AbsoluteHarmony Ok sorry. I will edit and fix the answer